# Как правильно писать следующее предложение

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Что должно быть у водителя такси:
1......
2.......
3......
6. Фонарь оранжевого цвета. Ни красного, ни желтого, ни белого.

Comment: Автотранспортное средство должно быть укомплектовано: аптечкой; знаком аварийной остановки; огнетушителем; запасным колесом; шанцевым инструментом; для перевозки детей младше 12 лет — специальным удерживающим устройством.
Источник: http://provodim24.ru/pravila-perevozki-passazhirov-v-taksi.html

Answer (score 2):

**Фонарь оранжевого цвета (не красного, не желтого, не белого).**

Здесь НЕ - отрицание (НЕ красного, а оранжевого, и т. п.)